# iPhone SDK: Why is didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being fired?

Tags: iphone

I have a view with a table on it. When the app starts, it loads the first 5 visble cells. That works as expected.

My problem is that, when I try to scroll down in the table the app crashes with this error.

What I've found is that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called. AFAIK, all I need to do is to subscribe to the delegate. But I must be missing something?

```
@interface LandingRetailersViewController : TableSectionHeaderViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITabBarDelegate> {
```

Any help appreciated.

> 2010-06-06 12:25:42.547
>   iphoneos[18238:207] *** -[NSCFString
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x451a980 2010-06-06 12:25:42.549
>   iphoneos[18238:207] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSCFString
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x451a980'

Here is my code to load cells.

```
UITableViewCell * cell = nil;
NSInteger index = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];

NSLog(@"WHAT IS INDEX %i", indexPath);


RoundedGradientTableViewCell *retailerCell = (RoundedGradientTableViewCell *)[tb dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RET"];
if(!retailerCell){
    retailerCell = [[[RoundedGradientTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"RET"] autorelease];
}

[retailerCell setArcSize:5.0];
[retailerCell setStrokeSize:1.0];
[retailerCell setStrokeColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[retailerCell setBackgroundFillColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[retailerCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Retailer *retailer = [self retailerAtIndex:index];  
if(retailer){
    [[retailerCell textLabel] setText:[retailer name]];
    if([retailer hasImage]){
        [[retailerCell contentImageView] setImage:[retailer image]];
    }
} else {
    [[retailerCell textLabel] setText:@"No title"];
}
cell = retailerCell;
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];



NSLog(@"retailer: %@ ", [retailer name]);
NSLog(@"log: %i ", index);

return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if this is your interface declaration:

```
@interface LandingRetailersViewController : 
TableSectionHeaderViewController <UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate, UITabBarDelegate>
```

And you are getting an exception thrown from this line of code:

```
-[NSCFString tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
```

The fact of the matter is that your tableView's `dataSource` property is set to a string object.  You can't send a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` message to a string object.  My first question is, what is a `TableSectionHeaderViewController`?  That's what your object inherits from, but that's not something I'm familiar with.  Generally, I would suggest providing more code in the future.

In any case, the bottom line is that your tableView's `dataSource` property is set to a string object.  Look into where that is set and exactly what object it is being set to.  If you provide more code I can help more, but I think you can take it from here. :)